# how to reload the nodejs app after making changes to the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a simple js file with http module to test `Hello node` for nodejs....

below is the `http_test.js` file

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello node');
}).listen(8080);
```

`node http_test.js` prints fine on the browser...now if i change my response line to say `res.end('changed hello node to hello stoner');`, i still get previous `hello node` on my page....

to get the changed line i got to end the current instance of node and then again run
`node http_test.js`

if i make any changes to js file should i restart over?

wouldnt just hitting refresh on my browser do it?

Comment: Take a look at [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), this would be one option.

Comment: Hitting refresh on the browser doesn't restart the node instance. In order for node to pick up the changes it has to be restarted and read the file again

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to stop and re run the server to see your latest update. To automate this, you can use `nodemon`, do `npm i nodemon -g`

And run `nodemon http_test.js`

Now, for every change you make to`http_test.js` the server will be restarted automatically

Comment: What is the correct way to do this when the code you are updating is in production? Is there a graceful automatic restart in Node.js like in Apache?

Comment: @tonix Redploy your app gracefully through a pipeline

Comment: @IanSmith Is there a resource or an article where I can deepen this? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

1) Install nodemon. To install,  from your terminal run:

npm install -g nodemon

2) Now, go to terminal, where you have the program. And, run

nodemon http_test.js

Now, everytime when you make changes to your app, just save your changes and it will get reflected.

Details :-

Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development. Install it using npm.

Just use nodemon instead of node to run your code, and now your process will automatically restart when your code changes.

Please refer :-

http://nodemon.io/

https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your server, because the file had load to the memory .
Or you can use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) who auto restart your server when you change file.

Answer (score 0):

I created a nodejs loader for this situation: https://github.com/braidnetworks/dynohot

In this case you would modify the program as follows:

```
import http from 'node:http';

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello node');
}).listen(8080);

import.meta.hot?.accept();
import.meta.hot?.dispose(() => server.close());
```

And you would run the application via `node --loader dynohot http_test.js`. Be sure to add `"type": "module"` to your package.json file first. After that if you modify the string to 'hello node 2' and refresh in your browser you'll see the new text.

The advantage over nodemon is that dynohot can reload only the parts of the application which have changed without restarting the process. For larger applications the improvement in reactivity is very noticeable.